# What is the best approach to segregate customer data in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, amazon-s3

We have customer data that gets stored in Amazon S3 buckets. I would like to know the best approach to segregate customer data> I googled and found two options, but want to know which is the best approach:
A. Separate buckets for customers. Where each bucket represents a customer’s folder.
B. Separate customer folders in one bucket.

Comment: Segregation in a single bucket can be easily achieved with IAM policies, but the correct approach will depend on your business circumstances; do you have a business need to segregate data? If so how does it need to be segregated? Can it co-mingle with other data, or it has to be scoped to a unique prefix? These are business cases, and the correct answer is dependent on your business requirements.

Comment: Yes, we have a strong business need to segregate data. The intention is that customer A should not view customer B data. I was thinking of below steps for data segregation : (1) Put All customer data in one Bucket
(2) Create “Folders” for Each Customers, create individual credentials that give access to a particular folder in a bucket (This could be controlled by using KMS keys for each folders)
(3) Use “prefix” and “delimiter” within the bucket. 
(4) Create separate IAM rule for each customer.

Comment: What Exactly you mean by "Can it co-mingle with other data, or it has to be scoped to a unique prefix?"